# Sorting data in AngularJS table by column

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I'm working on a web application in AngularJS. Basically, it makes an HTTP request to a database server and displays information for all the claims in a table. The table shows 100 claims per page and there are ~131 pages. My problem is, when I try to sort the claim info by columns, it only sorts the claim information for each page and not for all the data (it's only working for the createdDate). Any ideas on how I con sort the data for the entire table (all pages) by column?

I'm very new to AngularJS MVC, am on a tight deadline, and haven't been able to implement ngTable (mainly because I don't understand where the $data and $dataset is coming from).

This is my view (HTML):

```
<div class="row" id="dvData">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover " >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'userName'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Pass Code
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'userName' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'userName' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
          </a>
        </th>

        <th>
          <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'claimNumber'; sortReverse =! sortReverse">
            Claim Number
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'claimNumber' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'claimNumber' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
          </a>
        </th>
        <th>Vehicle</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>
          <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'createdDate'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Created
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'createdDate' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'createdDate' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
          </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="claim in claimList | filter:{claimNumber:searchClaimNumber} | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
        <td>{{claim.userName==null?'Not Assigned':claim.userName}}</td>
        <td><a href="#/claim-details" ng-click="selectClaim(claim)">{{claim.claimNumber}}</a></td>
        <td>{{getVehicle(claim)}}</td>
        <td>{{getClaimStatus(claim)}}</td>
        <td>{{getClientName(claim)}}</td>
        <td>{{claim.createdDate| date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mma'}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

controller:

```
angular
    .module('mbeapp')
    .controller('DashboardController', [
        '$scope', 'ClaimService', 'SurveyDataService', '$state', '$http', 'NavigateService', 
        function($scope, ClaimService, SurveyDataService, $state, $http, NavigateService) {

            [...]
            $scope.sortType     = 'createdDate'; // set the default sort type
            $scope.sortReverse  = true;
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to sort the entire data, you have two options.

1. You can load all data from backend at once and create a front-end pagination. Sort/Search will filter the whole data set and change the pagination accordingly.
2. When user wants to sort/search, you can pass that information to backend and get a new set of data based on the criteria.

Option 1 is easy to implement but it's a bad choice when you have a large data set. Option 2 is the ideal way to achieve your goal.

**Sample Code**
In your controller, you can write a function like the following:

```
$scope.sortBy = function(keyName){
    $scope.sortReverse = !$scope.sortReverse;
    $scope.sortType = keyName;

    var reqParams = {
        sortBy: keyName,
        sortReverse: $scope.sortReverse
    };

    // do a $http request
    $http.get('http://apiUrl', reqParams).then(function(response){
        $scope.claimList = response.data; // update the claimList data 
    });
};
```

Sample table header may be like this:

```
<th>
    <a href="" ng-click="sortBy('userName')">Pass Code
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'userName' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'userName' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
    </a>
</th>
```

You also need to change the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="claim in claimList>
```

Comment: What does <tr ng-repeat="claim in claimList> need to be changed to?

Comment: I did that exact function except with $scope.claimList=response instead of response.data

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If not, please describe where you are facing problem now?